# Constant term in time series econometric models built on 1-st differences

Tags: time-series, modeling

Both dependent and independent variables I deal with are nonstationary series that become stationary after differentiating them once.

The problem is that I assume that the dependent variable has a certain constant value which does not depend on the explanatory variables' changes and should be estimated as the model's constant term. 
But the constant term is lost in the process of differentiation.

Does anyone know any method of dealing with that kind of problem?

Answer (score 3):

As @IrishStat said it depends on the model. One way of recovering constant is to use the mean value of the residuals. Note that this method relies strongly on certain assumptions. Here is the illustration. Suppose your model is

$$Y_t=\alpha + \beta X_t + \varepsilon_t$$

with

$$E(\varepsilon_t|X_t)=0$$

and you estimate it by

$$\Delta Y_t=\beta \Delta X_t+\Delta \varepsilon_t.$$

Suppose your estimate $\hat\beta$ is unbiased (or at least consistent). Define

$$\hat{e}_t=Y_t-\hat\beta X_t.$$

Substituting the true model we have

$$\hat{e}_t=\alpha+\varepsilon_t+(\beta-\hat\beta)X_t,$$

hence

$$E(\hat{e}_t|X_t)=\alpha,$$

if $\hat\beta$ is unbiased or

$$\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T\hat{e}_t\to \alpha,$$

if $\hat\beta$ is consistent.

So the natural estimate for $\alpha$ is

$$\hat{\alpha}=\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T(Y_t-\hat\beta X_t).$$

Note that the model assumption is critical here. However with care this trick can be applied in general.

Comment: There's some serial correlation and heteroskedasticity in the model which I handle using GLS but I guess heteroskedasticity wouldn't be the problem in using the trick you presented (thanks), yet serial correlation would, as the expected value of error term is the function of explanatory variables. Is this correct?

Comment: GLS doesn't render the error process i.i.d. , You need to incorporate ARIMA structure in conjunction with GLS to guarantee constant error variance in the presence of uncorrelated errors. Note well that neither of these transformations deal with Pulses,Level Shifts,Seasonal Pulses and/or Local Time trends that may remain in the residuals. Finally none of the above guarantees that the parameters have not changed over time. To review these concepts you might read some of my older responses to a myriad of previous questions.

Comment: This will be probably a naive question, but wouldn't incorporation of AR rerm - a lagged explained variable into the model make the situation worse? Wouldn't it result in a biased estimator? And why using GLS/WLS does not eradicate heteroskedasticity? I mean,it's not intuitive for me - for observations with lower weights shouldn't we have lower error terms and the other way round?

Answer (score 1):

All software I know allows the user to specify whether or not a constant is included in the model. What software are you using ? Do you wish to share data (coded or not) and the model you are trying to estimate and perhaps I caN shed some light on "stuff"

ADDITIONAL MATERIAL ADDED !

When Y and X can be rendered stationary by suitable differencing , we do so to IDENTIFY the relationship between Y and X. Just because Y and X need to be differenced for IDENTIFICATION PURPOSES does not mean the differencing needs to be incorporated into the Transfer Function (econometric model) . For example both Y and X may be non-stationary BUT  the relationship between Y and X may be as simple as  Y(t)=B0 + b1*X(T) +A(t) . If one was naive enough to difference both Y and X then one would be inducing an ARIMA component into the model viz.   [1-B]Y(t)=[1-B]X(t)+ [1-theta*B]*A(t) where the estimated theta1 would be aprroximately equal to 1.0. Some programs ( you can guess the usual suspects) actually ASSUME that differencing required for IDENTIFICATION is the same as differencing in the final ESTIMATED MODEL. Hope my commentary helps you !

Comment: I'm using Gretl, which has no option of specyfying constant when modeling on differences.  Which software has that option?

Comment: @robo, I am somewhat familiar with Gretl, as far as I remember it is certainly possible to specify constant. Which menu option are you choosing? Can you include the output of gretl model in your question?

Comment: @robo; I am aware of a few programs that can do this. I believe SAS can do this and AUTOBOX ( N.B. i am affiliated with this software ) can do this. To be truthful I am astonished that all programs don't have this feature.

Comment: Well, each software I know has an option of specyfying a constant term. The problem is that in Gretl you firstly have to transform series into differences and afterwards run analyses on these differences, so specyfying constant in that model is actually equivalent of specifying a trend term in a basic model. Using Gretl to model on differences you cannot directly estimate a constant in a basic model.